# Cross ratios of permutations of four points

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Express the cross ratios corresponding to the $24$ permutations of four points in terms of $\lambda=(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$.

So we have $$\lambda=(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{z_1-z_3}{z_1-z_4}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{z_2-z_3}{z_2-z_4}\right)}$$ Now, how can we write something like $\delta=(z_3,z_1,z_2,z_4)=\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{z_3-z_2}{z_3-z_4}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{z_1-z_2}{z_1-z_4}\right)}$ in terms of $\lambda$? The expression $z_1-z_2$ does not occur in $\lambda$. Is the exercise correct?

Comment: The exercise is correct. You can easily see what happens when you swap the first two or the last two points. It remains to see what happens when you swap the middle two points. $T \colon z \mapsto (z,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ is the Möbius transformation mapping $z_2 \mapsto 1; \; z_3 \mapsto 0;\; z_4 \mapsto \infty$, and $S \colon z \mapsto (z,z_3,z_2,z_4)$ maps $z_2 \mapsto 0;\, z_3 \mapsto 1;\, z_4 \mapsto \infty$. How are $S$ and $T$ related?

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't know how to relate them except to write out the whole algebraic expression, which doesn't seem to help as I mentioned. Maybe some more hint?

Comment: Think in mappings. $S \circ T^{-1}$ is a Möbius transformation that maps $0 \mapsto 1; 1\mapsto 0; \infty \mapsto \infty$. So what is $S\circ T^{-1}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer It must be the transformation $z\rightarrow 1-z$ then. This means operation $S$ is the same as operation $T$ followed by operation $z\rightarrow 1-z$.

Comment: This means $(z,z_3,z_2,z_4) = 1-(z,z_2,z_3,z_4)$.

Comment: Right. Or, $S(z) = 1 - T(z)$. Now, what does that say about $(z_1,z_3,z_2,z_4)$ in terms of $\lambda = (z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$? Okay, you found it before I finished typing.

Comment: @DanielFischer And it is true algebraically, although it's hard to come up with that!

Comment: Yes, algebraically, it's not obvious. But if you think of what the mappings do, it's pretty easy. When dealing with Möbius transformations (or cross ratios, the same thing), it's always good to think of the mappings to see if they unveil something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four permutations that don't change the value of the cross-ratio: the identity permutation and three others:
\begin{align}
(1\leftrightarrow2,\  3\leftrightarrow4) \\
(1\leftrightarrow3,\ 2\leftrightarrow4) \\
(1\leftrightarrow4,\ 2\leftrightarrow3)
\end{align}
Since there are $24$ permutations, you should get $24/4=6$ values.

The mappings
$$
\lambda\mapsto  1-\lambda,\text{ and }\lambda\mapsto \frac1\lambda,
$$
generate a group of $6$ with composition of functions as the group operation, isomorphic to the group of all permutations of six elements.  I'd try computing those six things in terms of $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$, and see if they are cross-ratios of permutations of those four.